# fancybox is not working correctly inside ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

Code Edited Please Reaview.
i'm trying to show fancybox after testing a value using ajax after clicking a link but the fancybox keeps disappearing and showing up for ever as it's inside a loop any solution ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.add_to_cart[pro_id]").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pro_name = $(this).attr("pro_name");
        var pro_id = $(this).attr("pro_id");
        var qst = "?pro=" + pro_id;
        var ajax = false;
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("get", "ajax/check_exists.php" + qst);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                var result = ajax.responseText;
                if (result == 'product in cart') {
                    alert(result);
                } else {
                    $("a.add_to_cart[pro_id=" + pro_id + "]").fancybox({
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
                    }).trigger('click');
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: What about `$("a.add_to_cart").click()` after adding the fancybox effect? Should trigger the fancybox click. But I recommend to unbind the initial `click` action first, if you're using this, otherwise this might interfere...

Comment: are you sure this selector exists at the moment of binding it to fancybox ? `$("a.add_to_cart[pro_id=" + pro_id + "]")` ... and what is its `href`?

Comment: $("a.add_to_cart").unbind("click");
$("a.add_to_cart[pro_id=" + pro_id + "]").fancybox({
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
                    }).trigger('click');
but other clicks won't work after unbind("click")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to unbind the event in order to prevent recursive click triggering:

```
$("a.add_to_cart").unbind("click"); 
$("a.add_to_cart").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
}).click();
```

But you should try to separate the elements because `unbind` will destroy the binding for all the elements with your `add_to_cart` class.

Try to set `id` instead of `class` for the elements and as selector, so that only the current clicked element's binding will be destroyed.

Comment: $("a.add_to_cart[id="+pro_id+"]").unbind("click");                                            
  $("a[id="+pro_id+"]").fancybox({
  'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
  }).click();

Answer (score 1):

Just add the click right after you apply the fancybox:

```
$("a.add_to_cart").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
}).click();
```

Comment: same problem fancybox keeps loading and disappearing forever

Comment: That's why you shouldn't trigger the click on the self element that you've defined your initial code. That's some kind of recursive. You could try something like `$("a.add_to_cart").unbind("click")` before adding the fancybox effect. If this works, I'd write it as an answer  that might get accepted ;)

Comment: ok we are close i've added $("a.add_to_cart").unbind("click"); just before the fancybox code and it shows only once but when clicking another link that returns 'product in cart' nothing happens at all the akert doesn't work because we have unbidden the click it's the last problem with this code thanks for the follow up and sure it'll be an accepted answer

Comment: $("a.add_to_cart[id="+pro_id+"]").unbind("click");                                            
  $("a[id="+pro_id+"]").fancybox({
  'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic' 
  }).click();